# Es posible añadir un valor a un array?

Tags: java, array

Resulta que tengo un array de enteros, y necesito añadir al array un valor que el usuario introduzca. Mi idea era pasar el array a arrayList, ya que según he leído al arrayList se le pueden añadir valores mientras que un array es fijo. El caso es que no se como pasar después el arrayList a array de nuevo. Esto es lo que tengo. Alguien podría decirme si lo que intento hacer es posible, o si hay otra forma mejor para hacerlo?

```
public static void añadirValorArray(Integer array[], Integer num){
    miArrayList=Arrays.asList(array);
    miArrayList.add(num);
    //Falta volver a pasarlo a array
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si es posible, al terminar de agregar elementos al `ArrayList` creas otro `Array` del tamaño de tu `ArrayList`.

```
      public static void añadirValorArray(Integer array[], Integer num){
         miArrayList=Arrays.asList(array);
         miArrayList.add(num);
         Integer[] nuevoArray = new Integer[miArrayList.size()]; 
         //Aquí convertimos la lista a arreglo nuevamente
         nuevoArray = miArrayList.toArray(nuevoArray);
      }
```

Otra forma mas simplificada sería estao...

```
        Integer[] nuevoArray = miArrayList.toArray(new Integer[miArrayList.size()]);
```

Si requieres que tu método regrese el array y lo tengas que asignar al array original, no será posible porque el array original tenia un tamaño menor.

**EDITADO**
Prueba este modo de pasarlo, no puedo probarlo en este moemnto...

```
      public static void añadirValorArray(Integer array[], Integer num){
         Collections.addAll(miArrayList,array);
         miArrayList.add(num);
         Integer[] nuevoArray = new Integer[miArrayList.size()]; 
         //Aquí convertimos la lista a arreglo nuevamente
         nuevoArray = miArrayList.toArray(nuevoArray);
      }
```

Cualquier cosa, me avisas y lo verifico.

Comment: Lo he intentado así, pero al intentar llamar al método Eclipse me muestra un error en la línea de miArrayList.add(num);

Comment: @pacomaral podrias mostrar el error? puede ser que `miArrayList` este declarado mal, debe ser así... `ArrayList<Integer> miArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: Alguna ocasión traté de crear un método similar pero un ejemplo y que no  marque error, como sería un ejemplo para usar este método? ya que recibe Integer array[] y no int array[]

Comment: Creo que el error está en el método `Arrays.asList(array)`, ya que dice que convierte el array en una lista de valores **fijos**, por tanto por eso muestra un error en miArrayList.add(num), ya que no se podrían añadir valores. Puede ser por eso? El error que me muestra es el siguiente

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at array_lista.main(array_lista.java:12)`

Comment: @pacomaral de casualidad es un java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException ? por eso preguntaba como usar este método.

Comment: @Jorgesys sí, ese mismo.

Comment: ok Paco, por esta razón siempre he optado por usar un ArrayList @AlbertoRojas como podríamos usar este método? =?

Comment: No me fijé y efectivamente asList() regresa una lista de valores fijos como bien lo dice @pacomaral. Si solo le agregas un elemento podrias hacerlo manualmente con un for sin la necesidad de usar una lista.

Comment: Yo evitaría usar por ejemplo la letra ñ (añadirValorArray), o caracteres acentuados en nombres de métodos, clases, etc...

Answer (score 2):

No puedes cambiar la medida de un array una vez que fue creado. La longitud de un array es **[inmutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html)**!.

Te sugiero usar un **[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)**:

```
List<Integer> miArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    miArrayList.add(12);
    miArrayList.add(24);
    miArrayList.add(4545);
```

tu método sería declarado de esta forma:

```
private static List<Integer> miArrayList;

public static void añadirValorArray(List<Integer> miArrayList, Integer num){
    miArrayList.add(num);  
}
```

y esta es una forma de como agregarías los datos al array, primeramente instanciando `ArrayList` y posteriormente podrías agregar uno o varios elementos a tu array:

```
miArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
miArrayList.add(12);
miArrayList.add(24);
miArrayList.add(4545);
```

Answer (score 2):

En Java una vez que un `array` esta inicializado es inmutable en tamaño por lo que no podrías agregar una nueva posición pero si modificar el dato que contienen.

Si estas obligado a usar `array` lo que puedes hacer es crear otro con un tamaño de `x+1`, consiguiendo con esto el espacio para guardar un dato más:

```
public static int[] añadirValorArray(int[] a, int e) {
   a  = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
   a[a.length - 1] = e;
   return a;
}
```

Por otra parte podrías usar listas `List<T>` las cuales son dinámicas y puedes añadir/quitar elementos de esta sin problemas de tamaño.

Answer (score 1):

Para responder a tu pregunta, si, lo que haces es posible (tomando en cuenta que `Arrays.asList()` te devuelve una implementación de `List` tipo `ArrayList`).

Lo que haces es copiar el arreglo en un `ArrayList` usando la clase utilitaria `Arrays`. `ArrayList` es una implementación de una lista respaldado con un arreglo interno, en que la implementación se preocupa de cambiar el arreglo interno por uno más grande o más chico dependiente de la cantidad de elementos.

**Pero** hay otra cosa que no va funcionar, si simplemente asignas el arreglo a array, porque tu usas un método `void` y `array` en este método es una variable local (porque es argumento). Si cambarías los valores dentro de arreglo, se reflejaría en el código afuere, pero si cambias el puntero por asignación de otro arreglo, no pasa nada afuera de tu método. Entonces tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
public static Integer[] añadirValorArray(Integer array[], Integer num){
    miArrayList=Arrays.asList(array);
    miArrayList.add(num);
    //Falta volver a pasarlo a array
    // dependiente como declaraste miArrayList puede ser que necesitas un cast
    array = miArrayList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    // ahora devolvemos el nuevo arreglo:
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás la solución más cómoda sea crear una clase `Entero` y así poder usar ArrayList con él.

```
public class Entero {
   private int n;
   Entero(){
      n=0;
   }
   public void set(int numero){
      n = numero;
   }
   public int get(){
      return n;
   }
}
```